# How do I dynamically update a div instantly when an item in a dropdownlist is selected?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

### Edit for clarity: When an item in the dropdownlist is selected, call a method in my controller which will return a partialview and update a div on my page.

---

I have a ActionLink PartialView which I want to be called every time I select a new item in the dropdown list to update a table I have on my webpage - how do I make this happen without needing to press a button?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCustomerId, Model.CustomerIDItem)
```

I can do a Request["selectedCustomerId"] to retrieve the value from it without any problems but my question really is about the dynamic part. The first idea was to connect AJAX to the dropdownlist or using JQuery but I have no idea how to actually make this work.

Thanks in advance.

### Edit 4:

Adding all of my code:

_**DefaultValuesView.cshtml:**

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCustomerId, Model.CustomerIDItem)

<div id="divValues">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_DefaultValuesPartialView");}
</div>
```

**DefaultValuesController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
            
public PartialViewResult DefaultValuesPartialView(string SelectedCustomerId)
       {
            Session["theCustomerId"] = Request["selectedCustomerId"];
            var model = new DefaultValuesModel
            {
                CustomerIDItem = GetCustomerIds(),
                FieldIDItem = GetValues(),
                CurrentValuesItem = GetCurrentValues()
            };

            model.TriggerOnLoad = true;

            this.customerId = Convert.ToInt32(Request["selectedCustomerId"]);
                
            errorMessage = "PartialView is loaded!";
            model.TriggerOnLoadMessage = errorMessage;
            return PartialView("_DefaultValuesPartialView", model);
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to load your data with the `SelectedCustomerId` or with the name of the customer?

Comment: I just need to call the action in the controller (loads a partialview) when the dropdown is changed. @brothers28

Comment: Ok then check out my answer. Right now you also have the additional parameter `id` wich represents the id of the Selected customer

Comment: Why do you have the `@RenderBody` and everything in your div?

Comment: @brothers28 I moved it out like 15 minutes ago, forgot to update that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCustomerId, Model.CustomerIDItem, new { @id = "customId" })
<div id="divValues">

</div>


$(function() {
    $("#customId").change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $('#divValues').load('@Url.Action("DefaultValuesPartialView", "DefaultValues")?selectedCustomerId=' + id, function (response, status, xhr) { 
             $("#divValues").html(response); 
        });
    });
});
```

Your controller Action then looks like this:

```
public PartialViewResult DefaultValuesPartialView(int? selectedCustomerId)
{
     Session["theCustomerId"] = selectedCustomerId.Value;
     var model = new DefaultValuesModel
     {
         CustomerIDItem = GetCustomerIds(),
         FieldIDItem = GetValues(),
         CurrentValuesItem = GetCurrentValues()
     };

     model.TriggerOnLoad = true;

     this.customerId = selectedCustomerId.Value;

     errorMessage = "PartialView is loaded!";
     model.TriggerOnLoadMessage = errorMessage;
     return PartialView("_DefaultValuesPartialView", model);
}
```

**Please consider that your Partial views name needs to bee the same as your controller action name.**

You load your data with the jQuery function `.load` this is a common way and I use everytime if I need to do something like you want to do

Comment: I'm trying to make @PaulZahra s solution currently, when I give up on that one I will try yours asap. Updated my main post because I get really confused with all the names and where to put them currently. Been working on this problem for many hours right now.

Comment: Hi @DanAndersson i updated my answer that it will perfectly fit the names you are using. You just need to copy it.

Comment: I've tried to use your solution and put some breakpoints and seen that it never enters the "public PartialViewResult DefaultValuesPartialView" when the value in the dropdown is changed.

Comment: Oh sorry mate see the error here. I updated my code. It should work now. Please keep me updated if you have any questions or errors

Comment: I don't see anywhere in this solution where it specifically tells it to update the divValues div. I do not want to reload the entire page which you do with the @Url.Action - but want to run the "DefaultValuesPartialView" method inside the div. Hope that clarifies. Also, just using this solution the table doesn't change at all and it still never enters  the "DefaultValuesPartialView" method

Comment: I updated my post to add the controller code if that helps.

Comment: Hi @DanAndersson I see what you want to do. I Updated my post now. I had there another error, but now it should be ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91178/discussion-between-brothers28-and-dan-andersson).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly this should do it (it uses JQuery)... [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7u0fs4v4/)

```
<select id="myDdl">
    <option value="AM">AM</option>
    <option value="PM">PM</option>
</select>
<div id="babylonAndTing">
    A up lad.
</div>

$(function() {
    $("#myDdl").change(function() {
        $("#babylonAndTing").text( $('option:selected', this).text() );
    });
});
```

**P.S. Hmm on second thoughts, I answered your question title 'How do I dynamically update a div instantly when an item in a dropdownlist is selected?', but your question text is asking something different?!?!? Ah well I'll leave this answer for the people who read your title and come here :p**

**Edit:**
As for your question in the text, try something like this...

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SelectCustomer", "MyControllerName", FormMethod.Post, null))
{ 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCustomerId, Model.CustomerIDItem)
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#SelectedCustomerId').change(function () {
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
    });
</script>

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectCustomer(int? selectedCustomerId)
{
    // Stuff goes here.
}
```

Comment: I guess the title could be a bit misleading - what I want is to call a method in my Controller when the dropdown is changed.

Comment: Will try it, posting results asap!

Comment: "Argument 3: cannot convert from string to system.wen.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions" on the "CascadingDropDown". Any ideas?

Comment: @DanAndersson changed the form declaration, give that a go.

Comment: Still can't make this work, any chance you want to give it another go? I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an ajax request to the partial view and get back just the HTML content of it.  The key is using `url: "@Url.Action("DefaultValuesPartialLayout")"` to get the right URL to load your partial from.

```
<div id="divValues">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_DefaultValuesPartialLayout");}
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedCustomerId)").change(function() {
        var selectedCustomerId = $("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedCustomerId)").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("DefaultValuesPartialView")",
            method: "GET",
            data: { SelectedCustomerId: selectedCustomerId },
            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                $("#divValues").html(data);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Huh, downvoters should be forced to comment! I was just thinking this was a nice and clean solution myself :S

Comment: Do you really want to access the id `@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedCustomerId)`? Did you ever tried if this works?

Comment: It wasn't me downvoting fyi, I updated my post - any chance you could take another look at it? It's really getting on my nerves that I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @brothers28 `IdFor` was added in MVC 5 iirc.  If you're using an earlier version of MVC, you need to either manually specify the ID or write your own IdFor algorithm.

Comment: @just.another.programmer thanks for the explanation didn't knew this is new in mvc 5...

Comment: @DanAndersson updated.  As I mentioned to brothers28 you might need to explicitly use `SelectedCustomerId` instead of the `IdFor` depending on your MVC version.